# Excel treeview- adding extra information to node?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a treeview which contains, per node, a key and text. However, there is a third piece of information I would like to attribute to each node. What is the cleanest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/088ff74f%28v=vs.60%29) attribute exists for just this purpose. You can store data of Variant type in each tree `Node`'s `Tag` property.

Otherwise, create a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and use a Scripting.Dictionary object to associate the extra data with your tree keys.

```
Dim node_data As New Scripting.Dictionary
tvw.Nodes.Add , , "Key1", "Node text"
node_data("Key1") = 42
```